# JSON filter using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

i have a JSON object which contains duplicated data. however these data can change 
but given the structure of this i need to organize this JSON based on a country

Please find the original JSON

```
{
    "dataList": [
        {
            "country": "AUS",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "AUS",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits ": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "AUS",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "AUS",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "US",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "US",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "US",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "US",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "US",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "CANADA",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "CANADA",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "CANADA",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "CANADA",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "CANADA",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        },
        {
            "country": "CANADA",
            "Cart": 1610950,
            "orders": 35670,
            "Viewed": 966570,
            "Visits": 32190
        }
    ]
}
```

UPDATED JSON

I need to organize these JSON into more meaningful forms such as

```
{
    "dataList":
    [
        {
          "country" : "AUS",
          "data" :
              [
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950, "orders" : 35670, "Viewed" : 966570, "Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                }
              ] 
        },
        {
          "country" : "CANADA",
          "data" :
              [
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                }
              ] 
        },
        {
          "country" : "US",
          "data" :
              [
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                },
                {
                    "Cart" : 1610950,"orders" : 35670,"Viewed" : 966570,"Visits" : 32190
                }
              ] 
        }

    ]
}
```

Is there anyway to convert the above JSON into the one below using javascript or jquery dynamically
I have the below code what what it does is to map 2 different array and convert 
to key value Pair. But i think it need to to be expanded.

```js
$.formatToJSON = function(datatest) {

    var array = {};
    var list = {};
    list.dataSet = [];
    var len = datatest.columnHeaders.length;
    var rows = datatest.rows.length;
    //  log("Column Length : "+len);
    //  log("Row Length    : "+rows);
    var j = 0;
    while (j != rows) {
        var i = 0;
        var array = {};
        while (i != len) {

            var name = datatest.columnHeaders[i].name;
            var pair = datatest.rows[j][i];
            //  log( name + " : "+pair);
            array[name] = pair;
            i += 1;
        }
        list.dataSet.push(array);
        j += 1;
    }
    /*log(list);*/
    return list;

    return this;
};
```

Comment: Please give us some insight into your process. What have you tried? How does your code look at the moment, and where do you get stuck?

Comment: Your original JSON doesn't parse btw.

Comment: pls fix (missing comms and quotes) your JSON first!

Comment: fixed and posted the updated JSON

Comment: @andy  but i need the top json to be converted in the below format country wise  currently i am getting country repeated with values.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got your original JSON to parse (there's a copy in the demo if you're struggling), this function will create the new structure:

```
function reorder(obj) {
    var out = { dataList: [] };
    var objs = obj.dataList;
    var tmp  = {};
    for (var i = 0, l = objs.length; i < l; i++) {
        var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objs[i]));
        var country = clone.country;
        if (!tmp[country]) { tmp[country] = []; }
        delete clone.country;
        tmp[country].push(clone);
        out.dataList.push(tmp);
    }
    return out;
}

reorder(obj);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5nb0739y/18/)

Note that I've changed the structure of your data a little because I think it makes a little more sense. Instead of having a `country` property, just use the object keys as the country name. It makes it a little easier to deal with imo.

For example, you can do `Object.keys(obj.dataList[0]);` to get a list of all the active countries without having to iterate over the data structure.

Comment: this is a second JSON . this JSON should be expected from the firsrt JSON.

Comment: Just realised that you're grouping by country. I've fixed my code. @Siddharth.

Comment: @Siddharth, don't forget to mark the best answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
var formatedData = new Array();
$(data.dataList).each(function(){
    var currentData = this;
    var detail = {"Cart": currentData.Cart,
        "orders": currentData.orders,
        "Viewed": currentData.Viewed,
        "Visits": currentData.Visits};
    var newData = jQuery.grep(formatedData,function(a){
    return a.country == currentData.country;
});
if(newData.length==0){
    newData = {country: this.country, data: [detail]};
    formatedData.push(newData);
}    
else{
    newData[0].data.push(detail);

}

});
console.log(formatedData);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kej9b7j7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function like

```
data.dataList.reduce(function(acc, el){
  var cur = acc.keys[el.country];
  if(!cur){
    acc.keys[el.country] = cur = {country:el.country, data:[]};
    acc.result.push(cur);
  }
  cur.data.push({
    Cart: el.Cart, orders: el.orders, Viewed:el.Viewed, Visits:el.Visits
  });
  return acc;
}, {keys:{}, result:[]});
```

```js
var data = {
  "dataList": [{
    "country": "AUS",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "AUS",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "AUS",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "AUS",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }]
};

document.getElementById('before').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
data.dataList = data.dataList.reduce(function(acc, el) {
  var cur = acc.keys[el.country];
  if (!cur) {
    acc.keys[el.country] = cur = {
      country: el.country,
      data: []
    };
    acc.result.push(cur);
  }
  console.log(el, el.Visits);
  cur.data.push({
    Cart: el.Cart,
    orders: el.orders,
    Viewed: el.Viewed,
    Visits: el.Visits
  });
  return acc;
}, {
  keys: {},
  result: []
}).result;

document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
```

```html
<div>Before:</div>
<pre id="before"></pre>
<div>Result:</div>
<pre id="res"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var res = {
  "dataList": []
};
var arr = $.map(data.dataList, function(value, key) {
  var fn = function(_arr) {
    return $.map(_arr, function(v, k) {
      var obj = {};
      if (k !== "country") {
        obj[k] = v
      };
      return k !== "country" ? obj : null
    })
  };
  if (!res.dataList.length || value.country === res.dataList[0].country) {
    if (res.dataList.length === 0) {
      res.dataList.push({
        country: value.country,
        data: []
      });
    } else {
      res.dataList[0].data = fn(value)
    }
  } else {
    if (res.dataList.length > 0 && res.dataList.every(function(v) {
      return value.country !== v.country
    })) {
      res.dataList.push({
        country: value.country,
        data: fn(value)
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```js
var data = {
  "dataList": [{
    "country": "AUS",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "AUS",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "AUS",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "AUS",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }, {
    "country": "CANADA",
    "Cart": 1610950,
    "orders": 35670,
    "Viewed": 966570,
    "Visits": 32190
  }]
};


var res = {
  "dataList": []
};
var arr = $.map(data.dataList, function(value, key) {
  var fn = function(_arr) {
    return $.map(_arr, function(v, k) {
      var obj = {};
      if (k !== "country") {
        obj[k] = v
      };
      return k !== "country" ? obj : null
    })
  };
  if (!res.dataList.length || value.country === res.dataList[0].country) {
    if (res.dataList.length === 0) {
      res.dataList.push({
        country: value.country,
        data: []
      });
    } else {
      res.dataList[0].data = fn(value)
    }
  } else {
    if (res.dataList.length > 0 && res.dataList.every(function(v) {
      return value.country !== v.country
    })) {
      res.dataList.push({
        country: value.country,
        data: fn(value)
      });
    }
  };
});

$("pre").text(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<pre></pre>
```